# How to add multiple rectangles on a function?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame to create a game where you build towers and stuff i made some code that will create a tower on the players position every time i press C. I noticed that if i press C to create a tower and then make another one the first one i made just disappears please can you help me solve this problem

```
towerstate = 'unbuilt'
towx = 0
towy = 200
towers = 0

def player_towers(xx, yy):
    global towerstate

    towerstate = 'built'

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), (xx, yy, 30, 30))





def game():
    global towx, towy, towerstate

    x = 15
    y = 200

    vel = 5

    on = True
    while on:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()

        lol = pygame.image.load('lol.png')
        screen.blit(lol, (0, 0))
        z = 0
        for layer in tiles:
            t = 0
            for tile in layer:
                 if tile == 'g':
                     screen.blit(gr, (t * 30, z * 30))
                 else:
                     screen.blit(W, (t * 30, z * 30))
                t += 1
            z += 1

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= vel
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += vel

    pl = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (190, 130, 0), (x, y, 30, 30))

    if keys[pygame.K_c]:
        towx = x
        towy = y
        player_towers(towx, towy, )
        towerstate = 'built'

    if towerstate == 'built':
        player_towers(towx, towy, )
        towerstate = 'built'

    if x <= 1:
        x = 0
    elif x >= 570:
        x = 570
    elif y <= 1:
        y = 0
    elif y >= 445:
        y = 445

    pygame.display.update()

on = True
while on:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            on = False
    game()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is the `lol` bitmap the background?

Comment: I think that `while on:` should be `if on:`, because there's no way to break out of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from your code, but I expect the issue is caused by the re-painting of the screen background.  This is erasing any existing rectangles, and the code does not remember previous rectangles drawn, so they disappear.

One way to fix this would be to simply create a list of previous triangles.  Each time one is drawn, simply remember that.

```
towerstate = 'unbuilt'
rectlist   = []         # remember all rectangles placed
towx = 0
towy = 200
towers = 0

def player_towers(xx, yy):
    global towerstate, rectlist

    towerstate = 'built'

    new_rect = pygame.Rect( xx, yy, 30, 30 )
    rectlist.append( new_rect )
    #pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), new_rect )  #<-- don't do here
```

Then in your main loop, *after* the background is re-painted, re-draw all the rectangles.

```
# ...  (near the end of main loop)
# Draw all the player's rectangles
for r in rectlist:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), r )

pygame.display.update()
```

Obviously this is a simple implementation for a single tower.  Buy you could have lists of lists, or do a `class` for tower to hold all the rectangles in a separate location, etc.